# Jquery Image swaping, using a select TEXT value not working

Tags: jquery

So I'm working on a site that is being put into x-cart.
There is a page where the customer can choose some options from a select box, and a image swatch changes.

Since the value is dynamic, I rigged it up to read from the text value instead.

```
if ($('option:contains("Bridal White 001")')){  
    $('.imgYarn').attr('src','/store/skin/common_files/images/yarn/tiny/bridal_white_001.jpg');  
}
```

Its not working :(
 Not only does it pull up the wrong image, but it swaps only once.
Can anyone explain to me whats happening how to solve this?

**broken page:**
[broken page link](http://allesandra.curvine.com/store/bridal/cassandra-stole.html)
(under "select yarn color, click ivory and it pulls up the platinum photo. The 2nd select menu will need to be coded up as well)
(You'll see in the source code that i also tried using .html() and .text() as well... )

[how it should work](http://allesandra.curvine.com/add-item.php)

Answer (score 0):

It may not be able to find the path , you should give the complete path

```
$('.imgYarn').attr('src','/store/skin/common_files/images/yarn/tiny/bridal_white_0



$('.imgYarn').attr('src','http://yourwebsite.com/store/skin/common_files/images/yarn/tiny/bridal_white_0
```

Comment: Changing the image path didn't make a difference.  Out of curiosity, I used the val method to look for the black color (whos value is temporarily "4143", and THAT works....   but as mentioned, I can't use that.

Comment: @Rhianon , can you debug this using firbug and see if it is getting into that function

Comment: can you check if this is getting executed or not if ($('option:contains("Bridal White 001")'))

Comment: I haven't used debug in firebug yet, so I'll figure out how to do that in the morning and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
if($(this).find('option:selected').text()=="Bridal White 001"){

 $('.imgYarn').attr('src','/store/skin/common_files/images/yarn/tiny/bridal_white_001.jpg');  

}
```

Comment: It didn't like this either, it wouldn't swap anything at all...  when I passed it into an alert, it just said [object][object]

Comment: you probably dont know what your were doing. Use firebug's console.log() instead of alert